# Build Failed when running ./gradlew install for rosjava

Tags: ros, build, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu version 10.10 maverick
ROS version electric
java 1.6.0

I get the following error:  Any HELP?
(I can post stacktrace if that helps)
(I should mention I already tried the suggestions at:
http://answers.ros.org/question/42748/rosjava_core-build-error-apache_xmlrpc_commoncompile/)

> Building > :apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':apache_xmlrpc_common:apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.569 secs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43929/build-failed-when-running-./gradlew-install-for-rosjava/) by [SCIAITeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3006/sciaiteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-09-16**:
Yes, please provide the stack trace, the command you run, and the gradle version (by running the command with --version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably don't have the JDK installed.

sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0